# NSSearchField keeps losing focus

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller, first-responder, nssearchfield

I've got an `NSSearchField` whose value is bound to a `NSArrayController` subclass's `query` string property. The array controller observes changes to query and updates its filter predicate based on the query. So every time the user types something the result is an instant search. Problem is, whenever the array controller's `filterPredicate` or `fetchPredicate` is set(or `fetch:` is called), the search field automatically loses focus and the window makes itself the first responder. User can only ever type a single character before the focus on the search field is lost. Can anyone think of why fetching an array controller would ever cause a change in first responder?

Comment: Do you have a search-action set as well?  I suspect that if an update to the field's value-binding is triggered there, the field will lose focus.

Comment: Nope. the target and action of the textfield are both nil.

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve that problem?